# how to create an += operator

Tags: c++, class

i have an hpp file that contains a class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstddef>      // size_t
#include <string>

class Book
{



//private:
    std::string _isbn;
    std::string _title;
    std::string _author;
    double      _price = 0.0;
};
```

the other class is:

```
class BookList
{
    
public:
    // Types and Exceptions
    enum class Position {TOP, BOTTOM};

    BookList & operator+=( const BookList & rhs);
    // TO DO
    // concatenates the rhs list to the end of this list

private:
    // Instance Attributes
    std::size_t _capacity; // maximum number of books that can be stored in the dynamic array
    std::size_t _books_array_size;  // number of books in the list
    Book * _bookArray; // the dynamic array of books
};
```

i have all the functions that i need to do except for the +=operator which needs to concatenate rhs list to the end of "this" list how would i approach this? at the moment i have this but it does not seem to work:

```
BookList & BookList::operator+=( const BookList & rhs)
 {
  // Concatenate the righthand side book list of books to this list
  // by repeatedly adding each book at the end of the current book list
  // as long as it does not exceed <_capacity>
  // If exceeds, then stop adding
     
     for(int i = 0; i < _capacity; ++i) {
         this->_bookArray->_isbn += rhs._bookArray->_isbn;
         this->_bookArray->_title += rhs._bookArray->_title;
         this->_bookArray->_author += rhs._bookArray->_author;
         
     }
     
     return *this;
}
```

Comment: Please implement an AddBook function first.

Comment: [*identifiers that begin with an underscore are reserved in the global namespace.*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) so don't use it. Just use `bookArray`, `isbn`...

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop to below;

```
for(int i = 0; i < rhs._books_array_size; ++i) {
         
         if ( _books_array_size < _capacity )
         {
             _bookArray[_books_array_size] = rhs[i];
             _books_array_size++;
         }
     }
```

You need to loop the size of `rhs` array not `_capacity` of `lhs`, and add book at the of `lhs` array.

Comment: what about a find function where i need to Locate the book in this book list and return the zero-based position
of that book. If the book does not exist, return the size of this
book list as an indicator the book does not exist. this is what i have but it just returns 0. ``````````````````````` std::size_t BookList::find( const Book & book ) const
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < _books_array_size; ++i) {
        if(this->_bookArray[i] == book)
            return i;
    }
    return _books_array_size;
}
````````````````````````````````

Comment: First you have to decide, how do you want to find `book` by isbn, title or author, then in your if statement compare `if ( _bookArray[i].title == book.title )`, but to do this you must have data members declared with public access, otherwise you have to write setter and getter functions.